# Subclass and override onTouchEvent

Tags: java, android, view, subclass, touch-event

I am trying to create a subclass that will extend and override the onTouchEvent method. However, I am unable to do so as I am not entirely sure how to go about it.

Can I place the override in a public class that extends Activity, or would it have to be a subclass that extends View? When I try to extend View, I get the error "There is no default construction available in 'android.view.View'.

I have never tried to subclass or override anything before, as I have never tried developing in Java before. I have to make a minor change to a code I have, where the developer is no longer available - so, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I place the override in a public class that extends Activity, or would it have to be a subclass that extends View?

Try sub-classing `View`.

> "There is no default constructor available in 'android.view.View'"

Just provide default implementations of all constructors from `View`
(calling the respective super constructors with the same signatures).
If you're using Eclipse, it can do it for you.